# Building a memory repository into a function, outputs as next inputs

Tags: r

I've built a quick and dirty elo calculator while experimenting with functions:

```
elo <- function(winner, loser, r1, r2){

    player <- c(winner, loser)

    K <- 32 # smoothing constant

    R1 <- 10^(r1/400)
    R2 <- 10^(r2/400)

    E1 <- R1 / (R1 + R2)
    E2 <- R2 / (R1 + R2) 

    S1 <- 1 # Win
    S2 <- 0 # Loss

    rp1 <- r1 + K * (S1 - E1)
    rp2 <- r2 + K * (S2 - E2)

    rating <- c(rp1, rp2)

    data.frame(player, rating)
}
```

Now I'd like to build a memory management (?)/ repository into the function that would be able to "remember" each elo score.

Right now I'm manually calculating elo with successive calls:

```
elo("M1", "A1", 2000, 2000)
elo("M1", "M2", 2016, 2000)
elo("A1", "M2", 1984.736, 1984)
elo("M2", "M1", 2000.7, 2031.264)
elo("M2", "A1", 2018.1, 2000.7)
```

I'd like to be able to just input the winner and loser (starting new players at 2000), and have the function print out the new result while storing the old value some how (with a system timestamp?)

Example:

```
elo("M1", "A1")
```

I just don't know where to start.

Any comments, constructive criticism is appreciated. Apologies if this is too broad!

Comment: Create an environment and assign whatever is desired as worth remembering into that object.

Comment: Remember it how? I don't understand what you are asking. In your example you are calling with different parameter values so what exactly would you store? There is the [memoise](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html) package that allow functions to recall values rather than re-compute but that doesn't seem quite like what you are doing here. The example feels incomplete because i'm not sure what your desired output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to keep "score" by writing and reading .csv files to a HDD:

```
elo <- function(winner, loser){

    setwd("/Users/firstlast/Documents/R/elo/")
    df <- read.csv("df.csv", header = TRUE)

    if (winner %in% df$player){
        df
    } else {
        df <- rbind(df, data.frame(player = winner, rating = 2000))
    }

    if (loser %in% df$player) {
        df 
    } else {
        df <- rbind(df, data.frame(player = loser, rating = 2000))
    }

    K <- 32 # smoothing constant

    r1 <- df[df$player == winner, 2]
    r2 <- df[df$player == loser, 2]

    R1 <- 10^(r1/400)
    R2 <- 10^(r2/400)

    E1 <- R1 / (R1 + R2)
    E2 <- R2 / (R1 + R2) 

    S1 <- 1 # Win
    S2 <- 0 # Loss

    rp1 <- r1 + K * (S1 - E1)
    rp2 <- r2 + K * (S2 - E2)

    df[df$player == winner, 2] <- rp1
    df[df$player == loser, 2] <- rp2

    write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names = FALSE)
    return(df)
}
```

How might I now add some historical functionality (i.e., keeping track of scores over time)?

And there has got to be a better way to add new players to the df dataframe... my if else control structures look hideous!

**EDIT**

df is structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    player = c("M1", "A1"), 
    rating = c(2000, 2000)
)
```